# Match Column to Column Names, add value to row/column of Matches

Tags: r, for-loop, match, apply, lapply

Match Column to Column Names, add value to row/column of Matches

My first question, so be sure to teach me a lesson

Given Data Frame

```
df<- structure(list(ID = c("ID001", "ID001", "ID003", "ID004", "ID003", 
                      "ID004"), ID001 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), ID002 = c(0L, 
                        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ID003 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), ID004 = c(1L, 
                           1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)) 



   ID     ID001 ID002 ID003 ID004
1 ID001     1     0     1     1
2 ID001     0     0     0     1
3 ID003     1     0     1     0
4 ID004     0     0     1     0
5 ID003     1     0     0     1
6 ID004     1     0     0     1
```

I have an inefficient for loop for updating entries where the 'ID' column is matching a column name, we add to the value

```
for(rows in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[rows, match(df[rows,'ID'], names(df))] <- df[rows, match(df[rows,'ID'], names(df))] + 1
}
```

> df

```
     ID ID001 ID002 ID003 ID004
1 ID001     2     0     1     1
2 ID001     1     0     0     1
3 ID003     1     0     2     0
4 ID004     0     0     1     1
5 ID003     1     0     1     1
6 ID004     1     0     0     2
```

this is the desired output.  But I need to run this on millions of rows and its slow. I'm guessing this can be improved more than one way, maybe with apply or similar, but I've not attempted this and hoping to see how its done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-ID, ~ifelse(ID == cur_column(), .+1, .)))
```

```
     ID ID001 ID002 ID003 ID004
1 ID001     2     0     1     1
2 ID001     1     0     0     1
3 ID003     1     0     2     0
4 ID004     0     0     1     1
5 ID003     1     0     1     1
6 ID004     1     0     0     2
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm more familiar with this sort of approach, and in testing it its lightening fast.

Answer (score 1):

Create a matrix with `row/column` position index and then do the assignment

```
i1 <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), match(df$ID, names(df)[-1]))
df[-1][i1] <- df[-1][i1] + 1
```

-output

```
> df
     ID ID001 ID002 ID003 ID004
1 ID001     2     0     1     1
2 ID001     1     0     0     1
3 ID003     1     0     2     0
4 ID004     0     0     1     1
5 ID003     1     0     1     1
6 ID004     1     0     0     2
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, ended up using the dplyr solution in next, because thats more in line with the way I usually think about it, but I'll tuck this away as a good approach as well